# Mysql casting for datetime to date not reflecting in output

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, casting

I've a table with a column which is of type datetime. I just tried to cast it to date using two queries, which are

1. `select cast(attendance_student.created_date as date) from attendance_student`
2. `select date(attendance_student.created_date) from attendance_student`

But both the times I'm getting output as

```
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
7/16/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Why can't I get the output in date format.

Here is my table script

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance_student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attendance_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_present` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_on_leave` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cocurricular_leave` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_activity_attendance` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `activity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_sms_sent` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_attendance_attendance_student` (`attendance_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id_student_attendance_student` (`student_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fk_activity_student_attendance_id` (`activity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected because the `DATE` function returns the date same as the given datetime with time as 00:00 or in 12 hours format 12:00 AM.

You could use `DATE_FORMAT` to get just the date part as string:

```
select date_format(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as created_date
from attendance_student
```